# Cliff's delta in python?

Tags: python, effect-size

I want to calculate Cliff's delta in Python.
After searching on [Bing](https://cn.bing.com/search?q=python%20cliff%27s%20delta&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=python%20mann-whitney%20test%20cliff%27s%20delta&sc=1-38&sk=&cvid=A8EDFE2D1A9F43C188F0FE2BCBAC3634), and stats.stackexchange.com, I am astonished that there is no such library implemented in Python.
I only found the package that is implemented in R.

I'm wondering if there is something, or it is a must that developers have to use R to calculate  Cliff’s delta or implement it by themselves in Python?

Comment: Have you seen this repository already? https://github.com/neilernst/cliffsDelta

Comment: For what do you want to calculate Cliff's delta? Two sets of observations, or for two distributions (using formulas rather than data)?

Comment: Did you encounter the Wikipedia page [about cliff's delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Effect_size_for_ordinal_data) which tells that you can just as well compute the Mann–Whitney U statistic? (or do you want to do more with it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it useful to search github when I want to find a particular function that isn't in the usual places I'd look:

https://github.com/search?q=cliff+delta

This result looks like your best bet

https://github.com/neilernst/cliffsDelta

> This is code to calculate the Cliff's Delta effect size metric, which strangely is not in NumPy/SciPy.stats.

The above code has now been converted into a package which can be found here

https://pypi.org/project/cliffs-delta/

Comment: Thanks! I test it and it works! Thanks again for suggesting to me that I should search on Github.